# Special Conditions regarding matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have a question regarding special conditions in matrices. What are all of the special conditions where $AB=BA$ for two square matrices $A$ and $ B$? Would this be asking for multiples of the identity? What are the special conditions? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "all of the special conditions"? Do you look for  $\{A\in Mat(n\times n)\mid AB=BA \forall B\in Mat(n\times n)\}$?

Comment: [Commuting matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices)

Answer (score 1):

If $B=p(A)$ for some polynomial $p$, then $AB=BA$.

A noteworthy converse case is where $A$ has a Jordan form with only one Jordan block per eigenvalue. In that case, if $AB=BA$ for some $B$, then $B=p(A)$ for some polynomial $p$.